# Is it possible to add the image/logo in the Summary Overlay Profile?

Tags: profile

Question says it all. Is this possible to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I just tried it just now. Add the field `Contacts` - `Image Url` to the profile.

Comment: this was so obvious!!! thank you Dave. I was looking thinking in English in French instance